# TesseractError: (-1073741819, u'') when using pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, hebrew, python-tesseract

I'm using pytesseract for images that include both English and Hebrew. On some of them it works fine but on others the following error occurs:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ocr.py", line 47, in 
>       text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang="heb+eng")
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 286, in image_to_string
>       return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 194, in run_and_get_output
>       run_tesseract(**kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 170, in run_tesseract
>       raise TesseractError(status_code, get_errors(error_string))
>   pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (-1073741819, u'')

I have installed heb.traineddata, so I'm not sure what may be the problem. On those images that produce this error, using "eng" only doesn't make the code fail, however ends up returning wrong results, ignoring the Hebrew text, obviously.

Why would pytesseract work on some files and on others won't?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us your code that is throwing this error?